# Sharing home partition between OSes

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

I'm going to install Debian, Ubuntu and FreeBSD on my laptop. Is there a way to have a shared home partition for all three?

Comment: Depending on filesystem format, I would say just have the single /home partition mounted on each OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is relatively easy to do.  [This](https://serverfault.com/questions/180504/common-home-for-a-couple-of-linux-distributions) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6344/different-linux-distros-sharing-the-same-home-folder) might help. They give some good advice on how to make it work.

A little note an partitions:

There are 2 types of partitions, primary and logical.

- You can only have up to 4 primary partitions.
- You can have unlimited logical partitions

Make your /home/ partition a primary partition. Since you already have three, this will max you out.  You may have problems with config file conflicts, so I would just mount a shared directory within each home directory to store common files.  This can be done with [fstab](http://www.ubuntux.org/edit-fstab-to-mount-partition-at-startup) (change the path to your home directory).